# ¿Cómo completar tabla HTML dinámicamente?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Espero me puedan ayudar lo que requiero es a completar la siguiente tabla, la cual contine consultas en PHP, MYSQL y código HTML.

Cuento con una tabla en la base de datos la cual recibe o se insertan múltiples datos, estos datos quiero consultarlos y rellenar los espacios de la tabla.

```js
[![**ESTA ES MI CONSULTA EN MYSQL EN LA CUAL PRETENDO OBTENER EL ARRAY DE LOS DATOS Y AGREGAR Y O A COMPLETAR LA TABLA.][2]][2]

[![**ESTA ES LA CONSULTA DONDE OBTENGO LOS CAMPOS** ][2]][2]

$query_impresion = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM reporteimpresion WHERE nOrdenId ='$list'");
        while($datos_impresion = $query_impresion->fetch_assoc()) {
              $sFecheInicio     = $datos_impresion['sFecheInicio'];   
              $sFechaTermino    = $datos_impresion['sFechaTermino'];   
              $nTime1           = $datos_impresion['nTime1'];   
              $nContador1       = $datos_impresion['nContador1'];   
              $nVelocidad1      = $datos_impresion['nVelocidad1'];   
              $nTarima1         = $datos_impresion['nTarima1'];  
              $sPiojo1          = $datos_impresion['sPiojo1'];   
              $sTono1           = $datos_impresion['sTono1'];   
              $sFallo1          = $datos_impresion['sFallo1'];   
              $sManchas1        = $datos_impresion['sManchas1'];   
              $sRayas1          = $datos_impresion['sRayas1'];   
              $sGrasada1        = $datos_impresion['sGrasada1'];  
              $sGotas1          = $datos_impresion['sGotas1'];  
              $sTexto1          = $datos_impresion['sTexto1'];   
              $sAborregada1     = $datos_impresion['sAborregada1'];   
              $sAntirepinte1    = $datos_impresion['sAntirepinte1'];   
              $sOtro1           = $datos_impresion['sOtro1'];   
              $sOtro10          = $datos_impresion['sOtro10']; 
              $sObservaciones   = $datos_impresion['sObservaciones'];
           
        }

[![La siguiete consulta muestra los campos de la tabla de la BD los cuales son para acompletar la tabla de los espacios bacios ][2]][2]

 **
 <?php
      $imput = '';
      $query = "SELECT *  FROM dmultiplesimprecion WHERE nOrden='$list' group by sTarimas ";
      $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
      $int="";
      while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $date = $reg['sTarimas'];
        $imput .='<td colspan="2" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$date.'</td>';
      
      ?>
```

```html
 
   <table >
        <tbody style="font: 11px 'Goudy Old Style',"><tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Hora</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $nTime1;?></td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $form;?><td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Contador</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $nContador1;?></td>
           
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Velocidad</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $nVelocidad1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Tarima</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $nTarima1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Piojos</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sPiojo1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Tonos fuera de carta de color </td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sTono1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Fallo de Hule</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sFallo1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Manchas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sManchas1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Rayas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sRayas1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Grasadas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sGrasada1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Gotas de Agua</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sGotas1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Texto Legible</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sTexto1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Impresion Aborregada</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sAborregada1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Antirepinte</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sAntirepinte1;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Otros</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sOtro1;?></td>
         </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left; ">Otros</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"><?php echo $sOtro10;?></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="t01"><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Agregar cajillas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
       </table >
```

Capturas de pantalla relevantes:

[image: something]

[image: something else]

Comment: Hola, creo que tu tabla deberias ponerla antes de que termine tu ciclo **while** para que te muestre todo el contenido de tu tabla de base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te comentaron anteriormente, puedes meter el bucle **while** dentro de la tabla, más o menos así:

```php
<?php
      $imput = '';
      $query = "SELECT *  FROM dmultiplesimprecion WHERE nOrden='$list' group by sTarimas ";
      $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
      $int="";
?>

<table>
   <tbody>
      while ($reg = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $date = $reg['sTarimas'];
        $imput .='<tr>
                     <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Hora</td>
                    <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$nTime1.'</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$form.'?><td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Contador</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$nContador1.'/td>
           
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Velocidad</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$nVelocidad1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Tarima</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$nTarima1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Piojos</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sPiojo1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Tonos fuera de carta de color </td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sTono1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Fallo de Hule</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sFallo1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Manchas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sManchas1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Rayas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sRayas1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Grasadas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sGrasada1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Gotas de Agua</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sGotas1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Texto Legible</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sTexto1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Impresion Aborregada</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sAborregada1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Antirepinte</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sAntirepinte1.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Otros</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sOtro1.'</td>
         </tr>
          <tr><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left; ">Otros</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;">'.$sOtro10.'</td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="t01"><td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E7E6E6; text-align: left;">Agregar cajillas</td>
            <td colspan="1" style="border: 1px solid black;"></td>
          </tr>';
   </tbody>
</table>
```